# Not updateable record set

Tags: aggregate, ms-access-2016

I have a set of records linked (1 to many) to another table. The data tables are called tblJobs and tblTasks.  I want to show 1) whose task is next 2) all the people who are involved in the tasks and 3) how many are done out of the total, and have this display for each Job.
As soon as I create a query that is aggregated (maybe there is a better way) I can no longer amend the main job data. If I try and create a subform with this info, I can't add subforms to continuous records in a form.
I'm doing all this in Access VBA.  Here's an example of data seen on form:

```
tblJob
Company Name: Smiths
Date Start: 01/01/2023
Data finished: Null
Job Completed: Null (Boolean)

tblTask

Task No: 1
Task: Write email
Who: Bob
Completed: Null (Boolean)

Task No: 2
Task: Create Contacts
Who: Fred
Completed: Null
```

So here I would want to show with the job data that Bob is next, the job involves Bob and Fred and 0 out of 2 task are completed.
Hope that makes sense and many thanks in advance.

I've tried all the data in one record but it locks the data.
Also tried subforms but the screen then only can show one job at a time (no longer Continuous). Currently I am able to show taks completed by placing a subform in a header of a separate form that only appears using OnCurrent. This only shows the data one record at a time. If there is a way to bring this to the main form, that would be great so all records can be seen at once. Let's start a conversation!

Comment: *Let's start a conversation!* - this is not a forum, it's a Q&A site. Try to ask one specific question. [ask] -- Aggregated data is always read-only.

Comment: OK, how can I show this data on the main form?

Comment: To simplify the question; how to show aggregated data in a continuous form so that the related data can still be updated. thanks